# Passing an array with prepareforsegue

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray

I trying to pass an array through prepareWithSegue but I get null when I launch the app

this is the code :

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.destinationViewController isEqual:@"table"]) {
        PersonsViewController *person= [[PersonsViewController alloc]init];
        [person setAnArray:anArray];

        person = segue.destinationViewController;
    }
}
```

and this is setAnArray method:

```
-(void)setAnArray:(NSMutableArray *)anArray
{
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:anArray];
    if (array != nil) {
        NSLog(@"array is copied !!");
    }
}
```

the data should pass from viewController(embedded with UINavigation Controller) to PersonViewController (which is tableview) and nothing shows on the table so I NSLogged the the array count and found it zero so I did some further checking with this code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if (array == nil) {
        NSLog(@"array is null");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"array count is %lu",(unsigned long)[array count]);
        return [array count];
    }
```

and I get array is null message.

please help me to fix this

Comment: this line person = segue.destinationViewController is over writing the person you allocated a few line's up. is segue.destinationViewController a PersonsViewController?

Comment: @andrewlattis That's definitely it. Good catch. Yes, you don't instantiate (`alloc`/`init`) the destination view controller in `prepareForSegue`. It's already instantiated for you. Andrew, if you post that as an answer, I'll up vote it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just allocate the view controller from the storyboard and pass the array in as a property of that view controller before you add it to the stack? i.e. avoid using prepareForSegue

```
-(void) buttonPressed:(UIButton*) sender
{
  UIStoryBoard *story = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard name"];
  YourViewController *vc = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];

  vc.array = <you array>


[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];


}
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but you ask why not instantiate the controller manually? There are many reasons: Because it defeats many benefits of storyboards. You no longer have a visual representation of your flow. You can't use unwind segues any more. If you don't have your push segue from one view controller to the other, the navigation bar won't show up by default while designing your scenes. Etc. There are lots of reasons to not manually instantiate scenes. Don't get me wrong, sometimes you have to do it this way, but it strikes me as a kludgy workaround. But generally there are better ways to do this.

Comment: I understand that storyboards are quite a nice way to oversee your project, however, they are quite limited in what they can do. Furthermore, if, for instance, your navigation bar was really important to you, you could segue from a ghost button. I personally don't see the benefit of storyboards other than for people who are very new to coding and can't visualise CGRects in their head

Answer (score 2):

when you assign segue.destinationViewController to person your over writing the person object you previously instantiated and assigned the array to.

you probably want to do something like this

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.destinationViewController isEqual:@"table"]) {
        [(PersonsViewController *) segue.destinationViewController setAnArray:anArray];
    }
}
```